# How can l set the values of a column in vaadin table to link or button?

Tags: java, vaadin

I need to convert values in column "anzahl" to links or buttons, and l am struggling with the structure of vaadin table. I am getting database values from mysql table name "SYSTEM" (within entity class System).

This is my table properties which l have defined:

```
private void initSystemTable() {
        JPAContainer<System> systems = new SystemServiceDB().getAllSystems();
        table_system.setSizeFull();
        table_system.setContainerDataSource(systems);
        table_system.setVisibleColumns(new Object[] { "softwarebezeichung", "version", "anzahl", "lizenzen" });
        table_system.setColumnHeader("softwarebezeichung", "Softwarebezeichung");
        table_system.setColumnHeader("version", "Version");
        table_system.setColumnHeader("anzahl", "Anzahl");
        table_system.setColumnHeader("lizenzen", "Vorhandene lizenzen");
        table_system.setImmediate(true);
    }
```

and class SystemServiceDB:

```
public class SystemServiceDB implements SystemService{

        @Override
    public JPAContainer<System> getAllSystems()
    {
        JPAContainer<System> systems = JPAContainerFactory.make(System.class, "help-pu");

        return systems; 
    }
}
```

This is my output table:

[image]

I can't use `addContainerProperty` to set the column as l load these values from mysql, I can't find the way to solve this problem. I will appreciate if anyone can help me to solve this.

```
table_system.addContainerProperty("anzahl", Link.class, null);
table_system.addContainerProperty("anzahl", Button.class, null);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use generated columns.

This is an example of a generated column with a button:

```
table.addGeneratedColumn("generated", new ColumnGenerator() {

        @Override
        public Component generateCell(Table source,
                    final Object itemId, Object columnId) {
            Button button = new Button("caption");
            //Listener for the button
            button.addClickListener(Event -> {
                //Your code
            });
            return button;
        }          
});
```

Comment: You can also override existing columns with the same approach.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. It convert the column values to button, but can't I name this button column with the values that l get from mysql?

Comment: Yes, you can. `table.addGeneratedColumn("your value from mysql", new ColumnGenerator());`

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer but l didn't get the idea to set the text in Button column. I was thinking to write a for loop from first till last line of the column and than set those values in Button, but l just can't figure out.

Comment: table_system.addGeneratedColumn("anzahl", new ColumnGenerator() { public Component generateCell(Table table_system, final Object itemId, Object columnId) {
    Button button = new Button(?);
    return button;
   }
  });} this "anzahl" means convert anzahl column to button but l can't figure out to set Button(?) this question mark to column values

Comment: If you want to set the column name, this name is the first attribute of addGeneratedColumn. If you want to set the button caption you can set in the constructor or calling `button.setCaption("caption");`

Comment: l do appreciate for your help